# Notation ; and | in probability distribution functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation

The title is the question actually. What is the difference between the notation $;$ and $|$ in distribution functions?

For example, the marginal distribution of $X$ is $f_X(x) = P(X \leq x ; \theta)$ or $f_X(x) = P(X \leq x | \theta)$

The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is: $$f_{X,Y}(x,y;\theta) = P(X \leq x,Y \leq y ; \theta)$$ or $$f_{X,Y}(x,y|\theta) = P(X \leq x,Y \leq y  |\theta)$$

The symbol $|$ denotes that something is GIVEN. The $;$?

Comment: The vertical line means "conditioned on"; the colon means "parametrised by"

Comment: @JoseAvilez thank you.So ; it is not conditioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those notations vary in use somewhat, but the idea is the same: they indicate that a probability distribution depends on the value of a parameter $\theta$. The $|$ is more suggestive of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_an_event_of_probability_zero), implying that the $\theta$ comes from another random variable.